# How to multi label text Classification using Deep learning

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, multilabel-classification

I am new to the multi-label text classification using Deep learning,
I have Data like this:

```
parent_pid   domain_tld         category_dz                            description_en
0   1000714377  douglas_de      Makeup > Face > Foundation              This fluid makeup provides long-lasting moistu...
1   1000753794  dm_de           Nails > Nail Care > Removers              The handy sample size ebelin nail polish remov...
2   1000790264  douglas_de       Nails > Nail Polish                       LE VERNIS by CHANEL:  a novel, ultra-resistant ...
3   1000805273  douglas_de     Makeup > Face > Foundation             Clinique's superbalanced makeup controls shine...
4   1000808310  douglas_de      Makeup > Lips > Lip Liner           Keeps lipstick in place The Quickliner for Lip...
```

How Can I categorize the above category products using Deep learning, please any one share me any blog or references.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [tutorial on a text-based classification with BERT encoder and Convolutional Neural Network](https://databasecamp.de/en/use-case/bert-sentiment-analysis). It should work as well with more than two classes.